# How to remove (?) while we convert our byte content from unicode to ansi character

Tags: .net, unicode, character-encoding

I need to convert the unicode characters to ansi characters

```
byte[] encode = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Default, report);
```

I use this piece of code. While I am viewing this I found that extra ? character is added 
in the first part

?FF EE 20 12

Comment: You are *not* converting "unicode characters" to "ansi characters" here - you are converting characters to their numeric representations in the default system encoding. Understanding this difference is essential to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful if you posted the input string as well as the output.

Encoding.Convert() will output a '?' when it tries to convert a character in the source that does not have a corresponding character in the target encoding.

The sequence at the start of your output looks suspiciously close to a Byte Order Mark (BOM).  ANSI codepages don't have these, so if your Unicode stream has a BOM at the start you might try stripping it off before passing the data to the converter.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, it looks like your input data contains stuff that shouldn't be in there (cf. [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393495/how-to-remove-while-we-convert-our-byte-content-from-unicode-to-ansi-characte/393506#393506)).

In the general case, when converting between encodings, you can **implement your own encoding fallback mechanism using the [`EncoderReplacementFallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoderreplacementfallback.aspx) class**. You could easily make it return empty for unsupported characters. Simply supply an `Encoding` that uses your fallback when converting.